# Jquery Uncaught SyntaxError

Tags: java, jquery, html, jsp

I've got a JSP which is outputting the following HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script> 
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I open this page in Chrome, I get:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : jquery-1.4.3.min.js 120
jquery-1.4.3.min.js:-1Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream. jquery-1.4.3.min.js -1
```

When I open is in IE 8, I get:

```
Message: Expected '}'
Line: 109
Char: 466
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:8080/jquery-1.4.3.min.js
```

I've had similar errors with JQuery 1.4.2 and with the unminified versions of the jQuery JavaScript.

Please could someone show me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE**

I've fixed my mime-types, but I still get an error. Now it is simply a

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Here are the response headers from the jQuery request on my server:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=32400, s-maxage=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:75134
Content-Type:text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 12 Nov 2010 11:28:21 GMT
Expires:Sat, 13 Nov 2010 11:28:21 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=100
Last-Modified:Fri, 12 Nov 2010 11:16:53 GMT
Pragma:cache
Server:Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (9.0.4.0.0)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

The response headers from Google's file are:

```
Age:119
Cache-Control:public, max-age=31536000
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:26769
Content-Type:text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 12 Nov 2010 11:26:22 GMT
Expires:Sat, 12 Nov 2011 11:26:22 GMT
Last-Modified:Fri, 15 Oct 2010 18:25:24 GMT
Server:sffe
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
```

The content types now look the same to me.

Any other ideas please?

---

**SOLVED**
The problem was nothing at all to do with jquery, mime types, etc.
It was our ant build file. There was a target in there (which we've had on this code for over 6 years) which tried to minimise any JS file using a regular expression search/replace. This was breaking the actual jQuery javascript file. D'oh!

Answer (score 2):

It looks likely that your server is misconfigured, and is sending .js files as `application/octet-stream` instead of as `text/javascript`. I'm not sure why this would cause parsing errors like the ones you seem to be getting, though.

If you use the Google CDN URL for jQuery (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js) do you get the same error?

Comment: It works with the google file. Let me double check my server config.

Comment: I've tried updating my mime-types to match Google's, but I still get an error. I've updated the question with the details. If you've any other ideas, then they would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have something outside the question happening, some other includes interfering.  These don't match up:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
```

Note it's **1.4.3**, while your error is **1.4.2**:

```
URI: http://localhost:8080/jquery-1.4.2.min.js
```

Check for another file *before* your jQuery include that doesn't have a proper closing brace.

Comment: sorry - I was cutting and pasting from various windows when creating the post. I get the error when all the jQuery versions and file names are correct.

Comment: Hi - just re-reading your comment... I don't have any prior include before jQuery's. JQuery's include is the only one in the HTML - the HTML is exactly as above.

Comment: @A_M - what files are being included before?

Comment: None. Please see the HTML above.

Comment: @A_M - are you saying you're including *no* other files?

Comment: I am - I constructed the simplest example possible which exhibited the error. All I am doing is creating a page which included the jquery JS file, and even in it's minimal form, it still exhibits the error.

Comment: @A_M - What does your file look like, do you have a link? The obvious question would be...did you try getting a fresh copy of jQuery 1.4.3? If so, did you disable any user scripts/addons that may be interfering as well?